# How can I set Spatial Sound/Dobly Atoms in Windows 10 programatically?

Tags: audio, spatial, surround

I am trying to change or apply Spatial Sound in Windows 10 programmatically.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/spatial-sound

Unfortunately I found no answer from Microsoft Docs. What I want is

a) Enumerate all Spatial Sounds, like Windows Sonic, Dolby Atoms or DTS Sound.

b) Apply/remove some spatial sound from Audio Endpoint.
[Spatial Sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKNad.png)

From docs, it mentions

**When using the ISpatialAudioClient interfaces on an Xbox One Development Kit (XDK) title, you must first call EnableSpatialAudio before calling IMMDeviceEnumerator::EnumAudioEndpoints or IMMDeviceEnumerator::GetDefaultAudioEndpoint. Failure to do so will result in an E_NOINTERFACE error being returned from the call to Activate. EnableSpatialAudio is only available for XDK titles, and does not need to be called for Universal Windows Platform apps running on Xbox One, nor for any non-Xbox One devices.**

Does it mean that only xdk is able to turn spatial sound on/off programmatically?

Comment: Any luck with this? I am trying to do the same thing but also can't figure it out